# Running powershell function from .cmd file

Tags: powershell, cmd

Hi all,

I am a beginner with powershell. I created a MyPoweshell.ps1 file as follows:

```
MyFunction1
MyFunction2

Function MyFunction1 {

}

Function MyFunction2{

}
```

1) When creating a .cmd file to run the script nothing seems to work except if I typed in the cmd console: Import-Module .\MyPoweshell.ps1.
But if I save that code in .cmd and double click the cmd it immediately close.
How to run powershell from cmd by double click on it without closing the screen ?

2) Trying to make a clickable shortcut that shows in .cmd but nothing works.
Example :  C:...\Program Files\MyFolder.
How to create a clickable shortcut ?

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a powershell function from CMD? See whats wrong here?

To call a powershell script from CMD enter the following:

```
powershell -file C:\yourscript.ps1
```

Also you need to define the functions before you call them so in yourscript.ps1 you would need to have this

```
Function MyFunction1 {
   # Do Stuff
}

Function MyFunction2{
   # Do Stuff
}

MyFunction1
MyFunction2
```

Comment: Hi Paul, your answer didnt seems to work, I am getting errors "the term 'MyFunction1' is not recognized as  cmdlet ..etc.

Comment: @loli you call the functions before defining them, put the function calls at the end of your script

Comment: At some point, when you will completely let go CMD, and use Powershell fully, from a Powershell console, you will see how powerful it is. Paul is trying to show you how to call it from CMD.

Comment: Thanks Paul that solve it. Just waiting for the shortcut answer (2).

Comment: @loli SO is for help with code and not a replacement for doing basic research but here you go http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140443